# Search query displays results it should not?

Tags: discussion, bug, search

There is the following search query that I use:

```
[*worklight*] is:question answers:0 duplicate:no closed:no
```

I don't know if it is just for me, or for more people (ahm, please use it...) but in the results I also see questions that have already been answered, whereas the search specifically should not search for those.

For example, this result shows up: [Blackberry 10 Webworks with Worklight Geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951511/blackberry-10-webworks-with-worklight-geolocation)
But it already has an answer...

Is there some indexing problem right now in Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search is pretty much broken right now, some kind of datacentre transition.

Use google search instead until it's fixed.

Comment: Not sure how Google is supposed to be alternative to this type of a query, but it is not that big of a deal. Thanks for the update.

Comment: @IdanAdar it's not a good alternative but it's the only one you've got until they fix things.

Comment: True, the search backend was last updated in June 2 and was never updated since then. It might take hours, days, weeks or months to fix. (Depends how busy the team is).

Comment: Came to see if answers previously seen in search but now missing had been reported. So helpful answer.

Comment: The temporarily-missing posts have returned to my search :-)